# What diffeomorphism does the Hamiltonian constraint generate?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, hamiltonian-formalism, constrained-dynamics, adm-formalism

Consider the Hamiltonian constraint $\mathcal H(x)$ in the ADM formalism. What diffeomorphism does this generate?

Comment: You need to smear the constraint with a test function. It generates refoliations, that is, time coordinate translations.

Comment: @Prof.Legolasov So $\int f(x)\mathcal H(x)$ causes $t\to t+f(x)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ADM formalism describes a completely constrained system, with the momentum constraints generating spatial change of coordinates. Consider:
\begin{align}
    \{\int\xi^{i}\mathcal{H}_{i}(x)\,\mathrm{d}^{3}x, q_{k\ell}(x')\}
    &=\{-2\int\xi^{i}D^{j}\pi_{ij}(x)\,\mathrm{d}^{3}x, q_{k\ell}(x')\}\\
    &=\{\int(\xi_{i}D_{j} + \xi_{j}D_{i})\pi^{ij}(x)\,\mathrm{d}^{3}x, q_{k\ell}(x')\}\\
    &= - (D_{k}\xi_{\ell}+D_{\ell}\xi_{k})\\
    &= -\mathcal{L}_{\xi}q_{k\ell},
  \end{align}
where $D$ is the covariant 3-derivative, $\xi^{i}$ parametrizes the transformation, and $\mathcal{L}$ is the Lie derivative. This means that $\mathcal{H}_{i}$ are generators of spatial coordinate transformations. The Poisson bracket for the momentum constraints and the $\pi^{ij}$ are a bit more complicated.

We are working on spatial hypersurfaces, so there is a question of what "$\mathcal{H}$ generates time translations" even means. The easy bracket is with $q_{ij}$, technically what these yield are "surface deformations". (On the horizon of a black hole, surface deformations are not equivalent to changes of coordinates which could be bad.)

Here are some exercises concerning the constraint "algebra" around the ADM formalism.

### I. Lie Derivative of the Metric

The Lie derivative of a metric along a vector $\xi^{a}$ is
\begin{equation*}
\mathcal{L}_{\xi}g_{ab} = g_{ac}\partial_{b}\xi^{c}+g_{bc}\partial_{a}\xi^{c}+\xi^{c}\partial_{c}g_{ab}
\end{equation*}
Show this may be rewritten as
\begin{equation*}
\mathcal{L}_{\xi}g_{ab} = \nabla_{a}\xi_{b}+\nabla_{b}\xi_{a}
\end{equation*}
where $\nabla$ is the standard covariant derivative.

### II. Constraints generate diffeomorphism

Recall that the Hamiltonian and momentum constraints are
\begin{equation*}
\mathcal{H} = \frac{16\pi G}{\sqrt{q}}\left(\pi_{ij}\pi^{ij}-\frac{1}{2}\pi^{2}\right)-\sqrt q (R^{(3)}-2\Lambda),\quad
\mathcal{H}^{i}=-2D_{j}\pi^{ij}
\end{equation*}
and $\pi^{ij} = \frac{1}{16\pi G}\sqrt{q}(K^{ij}-q^{ij}K)$
with $K_{ij} = \frac{1}{2N}(\partial_{t}q_{ij} - D_{i}N_{j} - D_{j}N_{i})$. Let
\begin{equation*}
H[\widehat{\xi}] = \int\left[\widehat{\xi}^{\bot}\mathcal{H}+\widehat{\xi}^{i}\mathcal{H}_{i}\right]\mathrm{d}^{3}x.
\end{equation*}
Show that $H[\widehat{\xi}]$ generates (spacetime) diffeomorphisms of
$q_{ij}$, that is,
\begin{equation*}
\left\{H[\widehat{\xi}], q_{ij}\right\} = (\mathcal{L}_{\xi}q)_{ij}
\end{equation*}
where $\mathcal{L}_{\xi}$ is the full spacetime Lie derivative and the
spacetime vector field $\xi^{\mu}$ is given by
\begin{equation*}
\widehat{\xi}^{\bot} = N\xi^{0},\quad\widehat{\xi}^{i} = \xi^{i}+N^{i}\xi^{0}
\end{equation*}
The parameters $(\widehat{\xi}^{\bot},\widehat{\xi}^{i})$ are known as "surface deformation" parameters.

(Hint: use problem 1 and express the Lie derivative of the spacetime metric in terms of the ADM decomposition.)

### III. Surface deformation algebra

Show that
\begin{equation*}
\left\{H[\widehat{\xi}], H[\widehat{\eta}]\right\} = H[\{\widehat{\xi},\widehat{\eta}\}_{SD}]
\end{equation*}
where the "surface deformation bracket" $\{-,-\}_{SD}$ is
\begin{align*}
  \{\widehat{\xi},\widehat{\eta}\}_{SD}^{\bot} &= \widehat{\xi}^{i}\partial_{i}\widehat{\eta}^{\bot}-\widehat{\eta}^{i}\partial_{i}\widehat{\xi}^{\bot}\\
  \{\widehat{\xi},\widehat{\eta}\}_{SD}^{i} &=
  \widehat{\eta}^{j}\partial_{j}\widehat{\xi}^{i}
  \widehat{\xi}^{j}\partial_{j}\widehat{\eta}^{i}
  +q^{ij}\left(\widehat{\xi}^{\bot}\partial_{j}\widehat{\eta}^{\bot} - \widehat{\eta}^{\bot}\partial_{j}\widehat{\xi}^{\bot}\right)
\end{align*}
Show that for purely spatial deformations ($\xi^{0}=\eta^{0}=0$), the surface deformation bracket is equal to the ordinary commutator.

(The surface deformation bracket is a "canonical" bracket, defined at one moment of time. For deformations with $\xi^{0}$ or $\eta^{0}$ nonzero, the commutator involves time derivatives; it can be shown that the time derivatives of $\xi^{\mu}$ and $\eta^{\mu}$ can be chosen so that the surface deformation bracket is again equal to the commutator.)

Comment: Fixing the typos and minor errors are clearly an exercise for the reader ;)

Comment: Hi Alex, how do you derive the surface deformation algebra? Are you just applying the Lie bracket of vector fields?

Comment: @dennis Well, if you are satisfied with exercise II, then a natural question to ask is "How does $H[\widehat{\xi}]$ behave when we take the Poisson bracket of it with itself?" This leads one to exercise III and the surface deformation algebra.

Comment: Yes absolutely. So my understanding is that $H[\hat\xi]$ is equivalent to $L_{X}$ where $X=\hat\xi^\perp n+\hat\xi^i\partial_i$ (where $n=\frac{1}{N}(\partial_0-N^i\partial_i)$ is the 'normal' vector in the ADM formalism). Therefore $\{H[\hat\xi],H[\hat\eta]\}=H[[X,Y]]$ where $Y=\hat\eta^\perp n+\hat\eta^i\partial_i$, and $[X,Y]$ is just the usual Lie bracket of vector fields (this follows from $[L_{X},L_{Y}]=L_{[X,Y]}$). continued...

Comment: But this doesn't reproduce your SD algebra: take for example $\hat\xi^i=\hat\eta^i=0$. Then $[X,Y]\propto n$, which means $\{H[\hat\xi],H[\hat\eta]\}$ is a Hamiltonian constraint (and not a spatial diffeomorphism constraint as it should be).

Comment: @dennis If you look carefully at the definitions, there is no problem with that conclusion. Recovering spatial diffeomorphism constraints requires $\widehat{\xi}^{\bot}=\widehat{\eta}^{\bot}=0$. See also Teitelboim's [How Commutators of Constraints Reflect the Spacetime Structure](http://srv2.fis.puc.cl/~mbanados/Cursos/TopicosRelatividadAvanzada/Teitelboim.pdf) for a more explicit analysis of these constraints.